# Transition to MainVC gives the empty View without subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I'm using this type of transition to `UIViewcontroller`:

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(MainVC(), animated: false)
```

And in result i want to receive the MainVC with all subviews... but i receive only empty main View without any subviews. What i did wrong?

**Update:**
I have the transition to MainVC, but it's empty, only initial View, without all subviews. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: from which function are you performing pop?

Comment: I call it from extension

Answer (score 0):

You should pass object of `MainVC()`

like below

```
let objOfMainVC = MainVC()
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(objOfMainVC, animated: false)
```

If you are using storyboard then

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let main = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC // set withIdentifier to your identifier that was set in your storyboard.
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(main, animated: false)
```

Comment: In both cases i have a transition to MainVC, but it's empty, only initial View, without all subviews. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference of `MainVC`. You can't just create a new instance of `MainVC()`

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    for vc in viewControllers {
        if let _ = vc as? MainVC {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Or if your MainVC is root view controller of navigation controller.

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: In both cases i have a transition to MainVC, but it's empty, only initial View, without all subviews. What is the reason?